# Residue theorem integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+\cos^2x}\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this integral

> $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+\cos^2x}\,dx$$

I have two double order poles at $$z^2=-3\pm2\sqrt2$$
I'm having trouble taking the limit and finding the residue of this double order pole $$\lim_{z\to-3+2\sqrt{2}}\frac{d}{dz}[(z-(-3+2\sqrt2)^2\frac{z}{(z-(-3+2\sqrt2)(z-(-3-2\sqrt2)}]$$
any help would be greatly appreciated it

Comment: What function of $\,z\,$ are you taking that has those complex numbers as poles??

Comment: the function is z^4+6z+1

Comment: Ok, from here we should have begun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make the change of variable $z=e^{ix}$. Then
$$
dx=\frac{1}{i}\frac{dz}{z},
$$
$$
\frac{1}{1+\cos^2x}=\frac{1}{1+(z+z^{-1})^2}=\frac{4\,z^2}{z^4+6\,z^2+1},
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{1+\cos^2x}=\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{4\,z}{z^4+6\,z^2+1}\,dz.
$$
To apply the residue theorem you need the poles inside the circle $\{|z|=1\}$, that is, the solutions of
$$
z^4+6\,z^2+1=0,\quad |z|<1.
$$
Solving for $z^2$ gives
$$
z^2=-3\pm2\,\sqrt2.
$$

There are no double poles. You are interested only on the poles in the unit disk. Since
$$
|-3-2\,\sqrt2|>1\text{ and }|-3+2\,\sqrt2|<1,
$$
you have to consider only
$$
z^2=2\,\sqrt2-3\ .
$$
This gives you two simple poles at
$$
z=\pm\sqrt{2\,\sqrt2-3\,}\ .
$$

Comment: I'm a still a bit confused. Basically my compex function I'm integrating is $$\frac{-4iz}{z^4+6z+1}dz$$ so how do I get the residue of the function at $$z=\pm\sqrt{(2\sqrt2-3)}$$?

Comment: I have added details to the answer.